# how to search contents of a file in lua

Tags: lua

I am trying to open a file and search for a particular string and associate my contents to that particular string for future use and save the file again.

So far, i managed to open a file and write contents to the file.But i am looking for the logic to search the contents of the file and look for a particular string and associate my data with that string. Its more like a look up table for future reference. So far my code looks like this

```
--write something to a file
function wrt2file(arg1)
  file=io.open("/test.txt","a+")
  file:write(arg1)
  file:close()
end

--to search for a string and associate a new string to it
function search(arg1,arg2,arg3)
--i m looking for a function which will search for the string(arg1) in the file(arg2) and stick arg3 that location so that it can be used as a look uptable.

end
wrt2file("hello")
local content="hello"
search(content,"hi.txt","world")
```

How to do this?

Comment: What do you mean with "associate my contents to that particular string for future use"? Can you give an example of the content of "hi.txt" before and after calling search()?

Comment: thanks for the reply
I am looking to search for a particular string and add a string to relate to it

for example
in my existing file,say I have string called "fruit". So i want to add a string called "apple" next to this string. So, i search for "fruit" and add a string next to it called "Apple".This way I have associated the string "fruit" with apple. So next time i look for "fruit" i can access apple.
I hope I was able to make it clear what I am trying to achieve. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look a [pattern-matching functions in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/20.1.html).

It is not clear to me if you want to replace a string in a file, or remember the location of a string in a file.

To replace, you would use the `gsub` function, which works like this:

```
-- the string you are searching in:
str = 'an example string with the word hello in it'

-- search for the word 'hello' and replace it with 'hello world',
-- and return a new string
new_str = str:gsub('hello', 'hello world')

-- new_str is 'an example string with the word hello world in it'
```

If you just want to remember where you can find a string in the file, you should probably use `find`, which works like this:

```
-- the string you are searching in:
str = 'an example string with the word hello in it'

-- search for the position of the word 'hello' in str
offset = str:find('hello')

-- offset now contains the number 33, which is the position
-- of the word 'hello' in str
-- save this position somewhere:
wrt2file(('world %d'):format(offset))
-- your '/test.txt' file now contains 'world 33'
```